# coldfusion-10 error: The value returned from the init_datetype function is not of type pagedatetype_cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

In coldfusion 10, I am getting the following ERROR:
    **"An exception occurred while invoking an event handler method from Application.cfc. The method name is: onRequestStart. "**

**Rootcause:Detail:** "If the component name is specified as a return type, it is possible that either a definition file for the component cannot be found or is not accessible. "

**RootCause:Message:** "The value returned from the init_pagedatetype_ver04 function is not of type gg2_pagedatetype_cfc_ver04. "

**Any Ideas what I am doing wrong? Here is the related files and related code **

**FILE #1: "\application.cfc"**

```
 <cfset THIS.mappings["/inc_CFC"]= getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())
        & "/inc_CFC" >

<cffunction name="onRequestStart">

  <!--- INIT page structure --->
  <cfset REQUEST.paths.msg= (getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())
         & "inc_CFC") >

  <cfset REQUEST.gg2_pageDataStruct= 0 >

  <cfinvoke 
     returnvariable="REQUEST.gg2_pageDataStruct" 
     component="inc_CFC.gg2_pagedatatype_cfc_ver04" 
     method="init_pagedatetype_ver04"></cfinvoke>
  . . . 
  </cffunction>
```

**FILE #1: "\inc_CFC\gg2_pagedatatype_cfc_ver04.cfc"**

```
  <cfcomponent  output="false"  
    displayname="gg2_pagedatetype_cfc_ver04"
    hint="Component/Class/Module that manages all business Data "  >
    . . . 
    <cffunction name="init_pagedatetype_ver04"
      returntype="gg2_pagedatetype_cfc_ver04"  output="false" >

     <cfset var LOCAL=StructNew()>

     <!--- Do nothing but create blank object / component for now.  Later on 
       user will call other functions to init parts of structure/component --->

     <cfreturn THIS> 
   </cffunction>

   . . . 
  </cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have some misspellings take a look at these:

```
gg2_pagedatatype_cfc_ver04
gg2_pagedatetype_cfc_ver04
```

One says `data` while the other says `date`. Make sure that all of your names and types match correctly, and your error will go away.

Comment: thank you, I will check that... I looked at it dozens of times, and did not even see that... I am surprised coldfusion did not give me a "Function not found" error? Maybe subconsciously, in the back of my mind, I figured if the function name did not match I would have received a different error.  Next time I get this error, I will make sure that I delete the component="name" from the cfinvoke and copy and paste the "name" from the cffunction name="..." I am calling!

Comment: Correction: Next time I get this error, I will make sure, by using copy and paste, that: (1) that the _displayname_ of the _cfcomponent_ matches the _filename_ of the _.cfc_ and (2) that the _returntype_ of _cffunction_ matches the _displayname_ of the _cfcomponent_

Comment: THANK YOU. That worked.  I applied my 2nd comment "Correction" and the error went away.

Comment: Great, don't forget to mark my response as the answer. The way I found the error was to copy the file name in Safari, press Cmd+F to search, and pasted it in. It only found two matches, so I knew you had things misspelled. Copy/Paste is definitely your friend.

Comment: Just don't worry about the displayname argument at all.  It serves no purpose.  It was just your file name / returntypes that were giving you problems here.  I'd also serious rethink your CFC-naming strategy.  A CFC name should describe some sort of object... what the heck is a "gg2_pagedatatype_cfc_ver04" ??

Comment: Part 3:"Gateways and Datasources

Comment: "gg2_pagedatatype_cfc_ver04" is coldfusion OOP object.  It is the name of my "Datasource" object.  I also have a Gateway called "gg2_pagedatamgr_cfc_ver04".  It is based upon Part 3:"Gateways and Datasources from learn.objectorientedcoldfusion.org.The "gg2" is the URI for my web site. "pagedatatype" is a singleton object that stores a single session (and point to a singletom) app specific info in one class. "ver_04" is needed, because I'm on a shared hosted webhost, and cannot reset the coldfusion server,so by renaming the version on the cfc, coldfusion is forced to "fetch" the cfc again.

Comment: "gg2_pagedatamgr_cfc_ver04" is a gateway object that contains all the business logic for the session.